# ModuleNotFoundError when using pyspark udf

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm using pyspark with Databricks.
I want to use pyspark udfs, but I get an error when I use the declarative assignment instead of the decorator. My code is in different modules and looks like this:

```
# src/lib/udfs.py
# Option 1 (works)

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def apply_transformation(value: str) -> str:
  return value
```

```
# src/lib/udfs.py
# Option 2 (doesn't work)

def apply_transformation(value: str) -> str:
  return value

udf_apply_transformation = udf(apply_transformation, StringType())
```

I execute some code like:

```
# tests/lib/test_udfs.py

# works
def test_udf(self):
  ...
  df.select(apply_transformation("value")).collect()

# doesn't work
def test_udf(self):
  ...
  df.select(udf_apply_transformation("value")).collect()
```

and I get the following error when executing the udf:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:47: in wrapper
  res = func(*args, **kwargs)
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/testing/utils.py:642: in assertDataFrameEqual
  actual_list = actual.collect()
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:42: in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:1364: in collect
  sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322: in __call__
  return_value = get_return_value(
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
a = ('xro1733', <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x7f839cd93220>, 'o1729', 'collectToPython')
kw = {}
converted = PythonException('\n An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.\n\'pyspark.seri...utor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\t... 1 more\n')
  def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    try:
      return f(*a, **kw)
    except Py4JJavaError as e:
      converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
      if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
        # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
        # JVM exception message.
>       raise converted from None
E       pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.PythonException:
E         An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
E       'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
E           return self.loads(obj)
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 540, in loads
E           return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src''. Full traceback below:
E       Traceback (most recent call last):
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
E           return self.loads(obj)
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 540, in loads
E           return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
E
E       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
E
E       pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
E           return self.loads(obj)
E         File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 540, in loads
E           return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:194: PythonException
```

I would really like to have the 2nd option working, because it makes testing way easier.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the VSCode Databricks extension, as mentioned here:
http://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode/issues/975